# How do I show multiple Admob interstitials?

Tags: admob, interstitial

I have two portions of code

Preload

```
interestial = [[GADInterstitial alloc] init];
[interestial loadRequest:request]
```

Show

```
[interestial presentFromRootViewController:]
```

What should I do to show interstitial next time properly ?
With ARC and without

Preload

```
if(arc) [interstitial release];
interstitial = [[GADInterstitial alloc] init];
[interstitial loadRequest:request]
```

Show

```
[interstitial presentFromRootViewController:self]
```

-- or

Init

```
interstitial = [[GADInterstitial alloc] init];
```

Preload

```
[interstitial loadRequest:request]
```

Show

```
[interstitial presentFromRootViewController:self]
```

-- or

Init

```
interstitial = [[GADInterstitial alloc] init];
[interstitial loadRequest:request];
```

Preload

```
// nothing
```

Show

```
[interstitial presentFromRootViewController:self];
[interstitial loadRequest:request];
```

If last option is not correct then how much time should I wait for preloading after present is called? or should I listen for delegate or wait for some user action to start preloading?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You should listen for the `interstitialDidDismissScreen:` method from [GADInterstitialDelegate](https://developers.google.com/mobile-ads-sdk/docs/admob/advanced#gadinterstitialdelegate). That'll tell you when you're finished with the first interstitial, and you can start preparing for the next one.

So you'll have something like:

```
// During init time.
self.interstitial = [[GADInterstitial alloc] init];
self.interstitial.adUnitID = MY_INTERSTITIAL_UNIT_ID;
self.interstitial.delegate = self;
[self.interstitial loadRequest:[GADRequest request]];

...


// During show time.
[self.interstitial presentFromRootViewController:self];

...

// When user dismisses the interstitial.
- (void)interstitialWillDismissScreen:(GADInterstitial *)interstitial {
  self.interstitial.delegate = nil;
  if (!arc) {
    [self.interstitial release];
  }

  // Prepare next interstitial.
  self.interstitial = [[GADInterstitial alloc] init];
  self.interstitial.adUnitID = MY_INTERSTITIAL_UNIT_ID;
  self.interstitial.delegate = self;
  [self.interstitial loadRequest:[GADRequest request]];
}
```

Comment: An updated guide on iOS AdMob interstitial events can be found here: https://developers.google.com/admob/ios/interstitial#ad_events